# Why the order of filter queries matter for SOLR

Tags: solr

When I change the order of fq parameters , the result is changing. Why?

I have 2 documents with value of role_allow is "Role2" and only the name of one of them is "Filename1".

This query works and returns only 1 document:

```
{
    query:"querystr" ,
      params:{
        wt:xml,
        fq:"role_allow:Role2",
        fq:"name:Filename1"
        }
}
```

But this does not, and returns 2 documents.

```
{
    query:"querystr" ,
      params:{
        wt:xml,
        fq:"name:Filename1",
        fq:"role_allow:Role2"
        }
}
```

If I use the second json object, SOLR returns all matches of fq:"role_allow:Role2" but fq:"name:Filename1" has no effect.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fq:"name:Filename1 AND role_allow:Role2"` for the query. There can only be one value with the same key so the last fq is the only one that will be effective and the first one will be ignored. With the single fq with AND it doesn't matter which way the clauses are and both of them matter.

Comment: But in documentation it says :The fq parameter can be specified multiple times in a query. Documents will only be included in the result if they are in the intersection of the document sets resulting from each instance of the parameter. In the example below, only documents which have a popularity greater then 10 and have a section of 0 will match.  fq=popularity:[10 TO *]&fq=section:0

Comment: Also it says : Also it says :The document sets from each filter query are cached independently. Thus, concerning the previous examples: use a single fq containing two mandatory clauses if those clauses appear together often, and use two separate fq parameters if they are relatively independent.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-Thefq%28FilterQuery%29Parameter

Comment: The problem is with your configuration. I assume it's JSON and in a dictionary you can not have two keys with same names. It's not an issue with Solr itself.

Comment: In terms of a performance gain, would it help if we were to have more general fq first (thus limiting the document search space) and then a more special fq?